# An Amazing Nonogram

Tags: mazes, nonogram

<sup>This is an entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #37: Rare and Endangered 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6389)</sup>

---

Come see the Amazing Nonogram! This puzzle will baffle  <sup><sub><sup><sub>no one</sub></sup></sub></sup> with it's incredibly complex  <sup><sub><sup><sub>(actually quite simple)</sub></sup></sub></sup> twists and turns! Come one, come all and get lost in this puzzling attraction!

[image: Logic grid puzzle]

<sup><sub>(Sorry if the image is a little hard to read I had to shrink it down a little in order to be able to upload it.)</sub></sup>

Comment: Wouldn't the mazes and nonogram tags make this a Fortnightly puzzle again? I thought this would definitely have fit the bill.

Comment: I hadn't thought of looking at the nonogram tag (mostly because I tend to forget what these are called.) I'll go check (Amusingly enough I put the name in the title >.<)

Comment: I rolled your last edit back because I think it fits the criteria (being primarily mazes and nonogram).

Comment: Hah, mazes are #50 now, so it doesn't fit anymore. Although I guess I did post it before mazes got that high.

Comment: Tied 50th; although I think you're okay because mazes wasn't in the top 50 when the challenge began (it's not in the list on the original challenge post!). Fun puzzle, too -- it's good to give it some publicity as I really enjoyed it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that the answer to the maze and nonogram is this:

> [image]

Comment: This is correct. I'm a little surprised it got solved that quickly (not that it was all that difficult, I just expected it to take longer)

Comment: Thanks! Prodigious use of the Excel highlighter and rot13(sbphfvat ba rirel bgure ebj naq pbyhza (vr. vtabevat gur yvarf jvgu bayl 1'f)) helped speed things up for me personally.

Comment: I actually used Excel with conditional formatting to make sure it was solvable hehe